# Software to run a slideshow and display specific EXIF data

Tags: display, photo-management, slideshow, digikam, exif

I am looking for software to display a slideshow of my many photos (in multiple folders/sub-folders).  In addition to randomly displaying a photo and then automatically moving to a different image, I want the display to also include the Photo meta-data in at least one of the EXIF data fields ("Image Description", "User Comment", "Document Name" or "Comment").

I discovered that digikam will display user comments with the photo slideshow and also writes the user comments to multiple EXIF fields, but I manually changed the EXIF data to test what happens and found that the original user comment is still displayed.  So I assume that digikam keeps the comments in its own database.

I want the displayed information to be extracted from the EXIF data.  Is there a way to make digikam get the comments from the EXIF data fields, rather than its own database, or is some other software a better match for what I need?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research (Google...), I have discovered "Nomacs".  The "Image Notes" panel that can be displayed with the image shows what is in the "Image Description" EXIF data field.  This appears to be a suitable solution for my requirement.